# passing arguments when scheduling a function with asyncio/aiocron

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using the `aiocron` library to schedule function calls for certain times of day. This is a minimal example of what I want to do. In this example, I want to send a "good morning" message every day at 8:00

```
class GoodMorningSayer:        
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def send_message(text):
        #insert fancy networking stuff here        

    @aiocron.crontab("0 8 * * *")
    @asyncio.coroutine
    def say_good_morning():
        yield from self.send_message("good morning!")
        # I don't have self here, so this will produce an error
```

Unfortunately, I have no way of getting `self` in my `say_good_morning` method, as `aiocron` obviously does not know or care what class the function it calls is in. This makes aiocron rather useless in my case, which is a shame. Is there any way I can get `self` in a function called by `aiocron`?

Comment: As I can say it's bad designed library, please never use it. It doesn't work with non-default event loops. Moreover, you have no way to correctly handle errors raised by `crontab` methods unless you wrap every method in `try/finally` block. There is no error the single handler for all problems, which is very annoying in practice.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov do you have any recommendations as to what I should use instead?

Comment: I believe writing own loop with sleeping in certain delay by `await asyncio.sleep(...)` my solve your problem without the need for extra libraries.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov ...but then I need to reinvent basically everything that aiocron/croniter already does

Comment: Don't afraid to reinvent a wheel if the wheel is not round.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov I have no reason to believe my wheel will be any more round

Comment: "Don't invent a triangular wheel when you have a squared one" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this myself for now by using a closure:

```
class GoodMorningSayer:
    def __init__(self):
        @aiocron.crontab("0 8 * * *")
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def on_morning()
            yield from self.send_message("good morning!")       

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def send_message(text):
        #insert fancy networking stuff here
```

In the actual program I wrapped this in some boilerplate that eventually calls self.say_good_morning to keep the code cleaner