# How do I make my Discord bot run a function every sunday at 0:00?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a Python discord bot created using `discord.py` and I would like it to run something every Sunday at 0:00.

How can I do that?
I'm using Python 3.7 and `discord.py` 1.3.2

Comment: On Windows, you should look at using Task Scheduler. It allows you to set arbitrary commands, including python modules/scripts, to run on schedule.

Comment: but what if I want to use it in my Python bot code?

Comment: Use command prompt commands executed from python? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-task-using-task-scheduler-command-prompt

Comment: I'm reading this article about the `python-crontab` package, which seems to be cross-platform. I don't have the bandwidth to work on an answer for this now, but good luck. https://stackabuse.com/scheduling-jobs-with-python-crontab/ ... or this: https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/

Comment: Use your system's scheduler.

Comment: @dspencer I host my Python a server (cPanel). I am searching for a module/library that let us include the schedule IN the main file.

Comment: @Gugu72 have you tried what's in this question? I figure if it works to schedule an operation for 30 minutes, you can just run it the first time on Sunday at midnight and schedule it for 168 hours :P https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624445/discord-py-how-to-schedule-a-operation-i-tried-using-schedule

Comment: @icedwater Yes but it is not what I'm looking for, because I don't want it to run every x time, but every Sunday.
But I just thought I could use that every day, and it checks if we are on Sunday

Comment: If you start from Sunday, every 168 hours you will be on a Sunday again. Leap seconds notwithstanding. Maybe run it every day, then do an external API call to time.is, or something? I don't know, either way, good luck.

Comment: 1. Yeah, but I want to be able to run it on all days :D
2. Yeah, I think I will do that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aiocron.

pip install aiocron

https://github.com/gawel/aiocron

Add below to your bot code before the bot.run(TOKEN)

```py
import aiocron

CHANNEL_ID=1234

@aiocron.crontab('0 * * * *')
async def cornjob1():
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send('Hour Cron Test')
```

Comment: Usefull addition: When running the job in a `Cog`, it's best to nest the job method into the `__init__` function, as the aicron lib doesn't know (and can't get) the `self` instance.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39005726/10401159

Answer (score 2):

**This is not a more efficient way for the provided interval but one way of doing it**

You can use python's [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) module.

```
import schedule

def job():
    "Write your job here "


if __name__=="__main__":

    schedule.every().sunday.at("00:00").do(job)      
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

**Update : Above programming is blocking.**

For the non blocking you can use the combination of threading and schedule in the below manner.

```
import threading

import schedule

def job():
    """Your job here"""

def threaded(func):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
    job_thread.start()

if __name__=="__main__":

    schedule.every().sunday.at("00:00").do(threaded,job)      
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        """you can write your other tasks here"""
```

This program creates an another thread for your scheduled job.

Comment: Yeah, I need it doesn't block my code. You said there are other ways, do you know other ways not blocking the code?

Comment: Thanks, even if I won't use it since it won't work with a discord bot.